# Ridge Regression worse results with more feature. Does it make sense?

Tags: time-series, lasso, ridge-regression, high-dimensional, out-of-sample

**PREMISE**

I am dealing with a regression problem with time-series data (of option prices data). In my setup, I need to use only piece-wise linear models or linear transformations of data. 
I took care of only using past data to forecast the future.

My metric is the OOS R2 with a rolling window scheme:

[image: Start from the bottom row and go up]

**DATASET**

My feature set is made of 81 features which may have strong (not perfect) multi-collinearity. Moreover, after the 40th feature, each additional feature has an increasingly larger number of missing values, which I set to zero. The idea is that if a price is missing I cannot buy that option and any imputation technique (e.g. mean, median, multivariate imputation, etc.) would instead give a price to that option and make it 'tradable'.

Since I want to preserve the zero values, when scaling the features I never subtract the mean.

**PROBLEM SETUP**

I tried multiple regressions with an increasing number of features. Precisely, 20 , 40 , 60 and all 80 features (entire dataset).

I would expect that as the number of features goes up the OOS R2 should also increase or at least stay unchanged.

**PROBLEM**

The opposite happens. As I include more features, the OOS R2 dramatically drops.
My intuition is that as the feature set gets larger, more and more of the missing values enter the regression, hence "disturbing" the regression algorithm somehow.

Has anyone faced the same sort of issue? Can my zero-imputation scheme be the source of the problem? What could be a better solution for missing values in my case?

In general, can Ridge regression have worse OOS Results as the number of features increases?

NOTE: 
1) I obtain the same results with LASSO, Random Forest and OLS. With OLS I was expecting such behaviour due to the multicollinearity in my dataset, which gets worse as the number of feature increases.

2) I would like to attach my code, but that would be impractical. For reference, I am replicating this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10035) if some good souls want to dive deeper into this issue.

Comment: definitely sounds like your missing value. can you explain what your data is (columns). you make it sound like it is the price of an option. but then setting the price to zero does not preserve missingness??

Comment: Yes, along the columns I have the time series of option prices. I set the price to zero in order to preserve missingness, but I thought it wouldn't hurt the fit that much. I could drop the observations with too many missing values, but that would reduce my dataset of more than 1/3 and create gaps in my time-series since some days would be dropped.

Comment: On the other hand, I could impute the missing prices with the mean or median. 

BUT

Firstly, I don't know if this would really benefit the fit of my regression. Secondly, it would not be a real experiment. Since I would be fitting my model on observations that in reality were not available at that time.

Comment: I definitely believe setting the missing to zero will impact your fit. So I would recommend imputing the data first.  That should be relatively easy to try.